# Loop through array and echo an array value by using the array key as a variable?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was wondering if its possible, to loop through an array but have each key as a variable?

My current code is below, with an example expected output:

```
<?php

   $arr = array(array('id' => 24, 'name' => 'luigi'), array('id' => 12, 'name' => 'luiginsd'));

   foreach ($arr as $value) {

      echo $id . '<br />';

   }

/*

which would output:

24<br />
12<br />

*/

?>
```

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php):

```
foreach ($arr as $value) {
   extract($value);
   echo $id.'<br />';
}
```

`extract` will iterate through an associative array and initialize a variable (presumably using variable variables) of the same name as the key in the array in the current scope containing the associated value.

Just for fun, here's what I think `extract` does under the hood:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
   $$key = $value;
}
```

Note that `extract` does **not** necessarily import these variables into global scope, they are imported into the current symbol table.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you avoid `extract()`; it makes tracing the origin/heritage of a variable impossible (without either assumptions or code execution). A much cleaner way to do this is:

```
foreach ($arr as $value) {
  echo $value['id'] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: fair enough; I think the OP asked for something s/he doesn't actually want, but good point.